# Potentially incorrect calculation of the character width when filling in the AcroForm field with the isComb attribute using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

When trying to write a 40-character string in Courier New font size 18 in a field with the isComb attribute set, it was found that the last character was being cut off. [example 1](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/-nD6MiFgqhwxTQ)

During the experiments, I came to the conclusion that the reason is the incorrect calculation of the character width in the insertGeneratedCombAppearance(...) method of the org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper class ( [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/8f4f92429994e335dea6193a58fb7a8e6339db3e/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/interactive/form/AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java#L674) ) and as a result - incorrect calculation of the indentation for the first character.
If I remove the division by 2, then everything starts working correctly. [example 2](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/GQqlAnEyLJPBDw)

I ask for advice - is this really a mistake or does dividing by 2 make any sense in this case? If this is not a mistake, then what should be done? Examples of filling out the document in two ways are attached.
[template](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/SVZ-1C7i27P8CQ)

Comment: Your links show a _403 Forbidden_ by _Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at azovkomeks.ru Port 443_.

Comment: @mkl I upload pdf to another service and edit links. Please, try again. if you can't download from this resource, please tell me which thread is the resource where I could add these files...

Comment: I think you found a bug. UnitsPerEm is 2048 in the font CourierNewPSMT, the code you pointed to assumes 1000 (which works for most fonts). I've created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5784

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks, I'll keep an eye on the changes.